# Strange result from R query to SQL Server database

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

Background: I'm working remotely to make R-shiny dashboard. I have been given permissions to a SQL Server database. I don't have any real experience with SQL Server. I have MySQL on my own machine, but I'm logging in to a virtual machine which has R-studio and access to the database.

My connection seems fine

```r
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", Server = DBServer, Database = "thedb", UID = DBUser, PWD = DBPassword)
```

I can run this query and get the right result:

```r
mydates <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT var1, datevar FROM table1 WHERE datevar IS NOT NULL"))
```

but when I run this query:

```r
mynames <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT names FROM table2"))
```

the result is:

```
1 #NAME?
2 #NAME?
3 #NAME?
4 #NAME?
5 #NAME?
6 #NAME?
```

I checked with the data warehouser and there are real names in the database - nothing looks like `#NAME?`.

Also, I do have permissions for both tables.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Update:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

works, as does

```
SELECT rowID, names FROM table2
```

but it still doesn't work if I only try to pull the names

Comment: It might be an encoding problem; I don't have enough experience in it to say much. Are you expecting different languages in the data?

Comment: I have an update:  If I instead query: mynames <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT rowID, names, var3 FROM table2")) it delivers as expected  
I don't understand why it fails when I query for names alone - checked spelling and it's correct

Comment: That's a new one ... I use the mssqlodbc driver all day every day, and I've never run into that. Very interesting! What driver (mssqlodbc vs freetds), version, and OS are you using?

Comment: Is this possibly something about position? Like R wants to make a df from the sql query and having only one column confuses it? Because I suppose a quick workaround is to just always extract 2 columns using the query and then just dump one if all i need is a list.

Comment: I don't think so, `dbGetQuery` is fairly straight-forward about returning frames. When you get that weird output, my guess is that `class(mynames)` is `"data.frame"`, but what does `dimnames(mynames)` return? I would *assume* something like `list(NULL, "name")` based on your query, anything else is ... weird.

Comment: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, windows 10

Comment: Ok, so class is data.frame BUT, dimnames is giving me a series of numbers e.g. "1" "2" etc

Comment: That's fine, likely counts to the number of rows ... what is the second group in the list? It should match the column names.

Comment: There isn't anything but the numbers.  For the moment, I'm just pulling at least 2 columns from the db and then dumping one if all I need is a list.

Comment: I am not sure if it's ok to ask this here - please let me know if not and I'll move the question, but you commented in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799476/r-dbgetquery-will-not-select-records-for-all-values-passed-in-params that "the DBI package, as written, does not support binding variable-length vectors"

Comment: By that do you mean that I should not query against a list of variable length - e.g. I do one query which gives me a list (of variable length) and then I use that paste in the list into the WHERE clause part -   i.e.      sqlq2 <- paste(" SELECT x,y,z FROM table1 JOIN table2 JOIN table3 ON x WHERE y =", paste(listfromquery1, collapse=" OR y ="))   mydf<- dbGetQuery(con, sqlq2)

Comment: DBI *used to* not bind parameters like that. I don't know when it changed, but when I started using it (years ago), it did not. (I recognize that it likely did support it when I wrote *that* comment.) I wrote a helper package that handled for me, so I didn't recognize that it bridged that gap. (Side note: I actually wrote -- a few weeks ago -- an internal git issue to investigate and make sure that all of database types I connect to all support this properly.)

Comment: But that seems (to me) to be tangential from *this* question, which suggests that there is something wrong with the data in this query. To really inform the R side of this, I strongly urge you to run this query outside of R (preferably using `sqlcmd` or `bcp`, the MS SQL Server bulk-access utilities) and edit your question to include the raw output from those commands. Why? It might be encoding or something else, and I'm not confident that R is helping or hurting this.

Comment: At this stage I haven't been allowed to use their SQL server. I'll ask the data warehouser if he will do the above for me.  is it ok to share the link to your git issue so i can follow?

Comment: It's an internal repo, and it's only to remind me to update my assumptions and (no longer required) enhancements to `DBI`. It would do you no good even if it were public. But I don't understand something: you said *"At this stage I haven't been allowed to use their SQL server"*, how are you doing anything if they haven't allowed you to connect? I didn't think one could *allow* queries and *disallow* bcp/sqlcmd, have you tried them? They are both in a free download from Microsoft.com.

Comment: so I'm not using my own R-studio- i have to login to a machine to use their R-studio then access from there the dbs - the computer I'm remote connecting to does not have anything downloaded onto it like MySQL or anything and I'm not allowed to download anything onto it - is there another way? I don't have an IT background - I'm a scientist so if I'm missing something obvious here please let me know :-)

Comment: In your remote RStudio, see if `Sys.which("bcp")` returns a non-empty path. If it is empty, see if `file.exists("/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp")` returns true. If either of those are good, then you should still be able to run a test by using something like `system('path/to/bcp -W -s , -Q "select ..." -o <sometempfile> -S <sqlhost> -U <user> -P "<pass>" -d <dbname>')` (replacing the `<words>` with appropriate values.

Comment: Thankyou!! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Turns out the problem is in the database - it updates regularly so the data warehouser hadn't found it.  All of the #NAME? junk came from someone processing data in excel.

Comment: So what is the correct procedure here? Do I delete this question because it ended up being nothing wrong with the R code? Or do I leave it in case someone else is getting this result too?

Comment: Aha! I'm so glad you found a resolution for your problem. Now that you identified that the `#NAME?` problem is due to *Excel* and not SQL or R, you can go either way. I don't be hurt if you completely dismiss this conversation :-)  (Thanks for coming back, too many of these discussions just ... go ... dormant.)

Comment: I'll leave it up in case it helps anyone.  Thanks for all of the help getting to the bottom of this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

LeanneB,

Sometimes when I'm not sure I have a column name correct, I'll try using either `SELECT * FROM table2` for smaller tables or if the table is massive `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table2` to see the specific column names available in that table. Once I know what column names I need, I adjust my query and remove the `SELECT *` or the `SELECT TOP 10 *` part and replace with the specific columns I want the query to return.